# Words not affected by hyphenation algorithm

Tags: hyphenation

I was wondering is there a way to find out which words are not affected by hyphenation algorithm?

Also, what would be the most appropriate (read: elegant) solution to deal with those words?

I was thinking to use a separate file (dictionary) with those words.

Comment: all words are affected in the sense that they are matched against the patterns in the pattern file for the current language, that may of course result in no hyphenation points. additional words can be added via `\hyphenation` (Barbara Beeton maintains an extensive extra hyphenation file for american english)

Comment: In addition to David Carlisle's comment, you can use `\showhyphens` to demonstrate the known hyphenation points in a given word/phrase (the output is in the log file).